# How can I store hashed password in sqlite android

Tags: java, android, sqlite, hash, cryptography

```
protected static byte[] getHashedKey(String password,String MODE)throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException {

    saltIV = new byte[48];
    salt = new byte[32];
    ivBytes =new byte[16];

    if(MODE.equals("CREATE_VAULT")){
        //generate salt ,iv & save them
        salt = generateSalt();
        ivBytes = generateIV();

        System.arraycopy(salt, 0, saltIV, 0, salt.length);
        System.arraycopy(ivBytes, 0, saltIV, salt.length, ivBytes.length);

        //save salt & iv
        //FileOutputStream saltIvOutFile = new FileOutputStream("C:\\saltIv.ats");
        //saltIvOutFile.write(saltIV);
        //saltIvOutFile.close();
    }
    if(MODE.equals("OPEN_VAULT")){
        FileInputStream saltIvInFile = new FileInputStream("C:\\saltIv.ats");
        saltIvInFile.read(saltIV);
        saltIvInFile.close();

        System.arraycopy(saltIV, 0, salt, 0, salt.length);
        System.arraycopy(saltIV, salt.length, ivBytes, 0, ivBytes.length);
    }

    // Derive the key
    SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256");
    PBEKeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(
            password.toCharArray(),
            salt,
            pswdIterations,
            keySize
    );

    SecretKey secretKey = factory.generateSecret(spec);

    return secretKey.getEncoded();
}
```

this is where the hashed password gets generated and

try {

```
String finalKey = Arrays.toString(androCrypter.getHashedKey(v.password,"CREATE_VAULT"));
                                } catch (IOException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                } catch (InvalidKeySpecException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                                boolean vaultCreationSuccessful = new TableController(context).addNewVault(finalKey,v.vaultName,v.algorithm);
```

this is where I save the hash as string and insert it to database
but it never gets saved.The sqlite column is TEXT type.I came to know that sqlite supports directly saving byte array so I tried with byte[] also but same result,no entry in database.There is nothing wrong with **addVault()** code as I have checked it with other normal string and all,it works just fine.
Here is the code

```
protected boolean addNewVault(String finalKey,String vaultName,String algorithm) {

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put("Vault_Name", vaultName);
        values.put("KEY", finalKey);
        values.put("Algorithm", algorithm);

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        boolean createSuccessful = db.insert(DATABASE_NAME, null, values) > 0;
        db.close();

        return createSuccessful;
    }
```

But in this case I cant get it to work.Nothing gets saved.I also read about BLOB but I think its not needed as because byte[] is supported in sqlite.
What is wrong ? 
Any help/suggestion would be really appreciated.Thank you.

NOTE:Please ignore the FileInputStream and FileOutputtream lines in getHashedKey();

EDIT:
I just figured out that this

```
try {
       finalKey = Arrays.toString(androCrypter.getHashedKey(v.password,"CREATE_VAULT"));
                                } catch (IOException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                } catch (InvalidKeySpecException e) {
```

code is not getting executed that is the problem. I have created another class just to check if it works there and it does.
Tried another method and calling it like finalKey= getFinalKey(v.password) and this method contains the above code but that does not work.
I am completely out of clue.Please help.

Comment: I save hashes as strings in my sqlite apps and work fine, it's just text. Some control questions: -do other values, tables or records get writen? -have you tried printing the values (especially the hash) to console prior to the insert? -have you debuged the application?

Comment: No other values get written to any other table.This is the single one. Yes I have shown the finalKey value as toast but its null as it is initialized.but the hash does gets generated as I have checked with a single java code and printing it to console. I have not debugged the application yet. Hpw do you save the hashes as string and the get back the same as byte[] , can you share some code/idea?

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is to convert the "byte[]" to String:

```
String hashAsString = new String(hashAsBytes,"UTF-8");
```

Where "hashAsBytes" is the the resulting of "getHashedKey", and "hashAsString" is your byte array converted to a String.

Then you just save the "hashAsString" in your DB, as you see fit.

Then to compare hashes:

```
public boolean compareHashes(String hashInDB, String hashNew){
    return hashInDB.equals(hashNew);
}
```

This method will return TRUE if your hashInDB is equal to the new hash you have just calculated. In case the hashes do not match it will return FALSE.

Hope this helps!

Best, Federico.

Comment: Already tried this previously... I dont know why it doesn't getting stored in sqlite. You save the string directly to database right?

Comment: Yes, absolutely I think the problem is in using SQLite, and not in handling strings or bytes. To access SQLite from Android I followed Google's approach: [SQLite android](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html). And it works fine. Are you sure that your DB is working?

Comment: Yes my db is working as I have checked it with simple values earlier just to make sure that its working.

Comment: Ok. So your DB does work but a simple String does not get stored??? There is something wrong with your code. Please debug the String storing process. You must have a bug there.

Comment: I figured out that finalKey remains the same as it was initialized. I just initialized finalKey = "Hello" and  later saved the hash to over right it but my database entry went successful and "Hello" got stored in place of the KEY column

Comment: So your DB is working fine! Now you should save the HashAsString instead of "Hello". Then just compare hashes and thats it. If you are having trouble with creating the hash then take a look at your "androCrypter.getHashedKey(v.password,"CREATE_VAULT")" line, and debug what is done inside. Personally I use MessageDigest to generate hashes.